# How to pass variable to WebPack module?

Tags: javascript, php, webpack

I'm trying to understand, how to use WebPack to bundle all my module specific JS source to a single file. For this sample I'm using just a single JS file.

Normally I would write my JavaScript and HTML like this:

**foo.js**

```
var foo = function (className) {
  this.className = null;

  this.init(className)
}

foo.prototype = {
  "init": function (className) {
    this.className = className
  },

  "render": function () {
    var o = document.createElement("span")

    o.setAttribute("class", this.className)
    o.textContent = "foo's className is " + this.className

    return o
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="foo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div id="foobar"></div>
    <script>
        ;(function () {
            var className = "bar"
            var o = new foo(className)

            document.getElementById("foobar").appendChild(o.render())
        })()
    </script>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Most times the script part gets injected by a PHP application and the value of the variable will come from some backend code.

Now I'm trying to bundle my JS code with WebPack. The **webpack.config.js** looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    bundle: [
      "./src/foo.js"
    ]
  },

  output: {
    filename: "dst/[name].js"
  }
}
```

I update the **foo.js** file:

```
...
module.exports = foo
```

Now I compile the bundle with *webpack -p*, Then I change the HTML to include the new bundle.js and require *foo*.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="dst/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div id="foobar"></div>
    <script>
        ;(function () {
            var foo = require("foo")
            var className = "bar"
            var o = new foo(className)

            document.getElementById("foobar").appendChild(o.render())
        })()
    </script>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

But now I just get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: requrie is not defined
    var foo = requrie("foo")
```

How can I make this code work with WebPack? Is WebPack even the right tool for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Update the **webpack.config.js** like this:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
      "./src/foo.js"
    ]
  },

  output: {
    library: "foo",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    filename: "dst/[name].js"
  }
}
```